# If messagebox is shown halt the rest execution of the function in c# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I have the following method that browse a file for the user.

```cs
public void BrowseFile(TextBox filanametextbox, TextBlock textblocname, DataGrid datagrid, Button browsebutton, Button loadbutton)
        {
            // Create OpenFileDialog
            OpenFileDialog openFileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();

            // Launch OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
            Nullable<bool> result = openFileDlg.ShowDialog();

            // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox.
            // Load content of file in a TextBlock
            if (result == true)
            {
                filanametextbox.Text = openFileDlg.FileName;
                textblocname.Text = "Created on: " + File.GetCreationTime(openFileDlg.FileName).ToString() + "\n";

                //Debug.WriteLine(File.GetCreationTime(openFileDlg.FileName).ToString());

                var datatablematrix = ConvertToDataTable(filePath: openFileDlg.FileName);

                if (browsebutton.Name.ToString()=="BrowseButton")
                {
                    if (!filanametextbox.Text.Contains("Files.csv"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The file imported is an invalid format file! \n Please check that you have imported the correct one.", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                    }
                }

                else if (browsebutton.Name.ToString()=="BrowseButtonLayout")
                {
                    if (!filanametextbox.Text.Contains("Layout.csv"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The file imported is an invalid layout file! \n Please check that you have imported the correct one.", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                    }
                }

                else if (browsebutton.Name.ToString() == "BrowseButtonBC")
                {
                    if (!filanametextbox.Text.Contains("BusinessChecks.csv"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The file imported is an invalid business checks file! \n Please check that you have imported the correct one.", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                    }
                }

                datagrid.DataContext = datatablematrix.DefaultView;
            }

            // Set filter for file extension and default file extension  
            openFileDlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            openFileDlg.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            // Set initial directory
            openFileDlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Documents\";

            // Multiple selection with all file types    
            openFileDlg.Multiselect = true;

            browsebutton.IsEnabled = true;
            loadbutton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

What I want somehow is when the message box is triggered by one of the three if-statements to halt the execution for the rest of the function. Which means that the Data table won't get filled and the loadbutton won't be enabled whatsoever.

*Initial state of the app*

[image]

*State on message box*

[image]

When the user will click OK on the message box I want the Load Button to still be disabled and the Data Grid table (black box) not filled with values.

Searching online I found this SO question, which argues to create a bool function. Although, I am not quite sure how to embed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744154/how-to-stop-function-once-message-box-displayed) solution in my single function.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just to use return, when you show your Message Box ?

Comment: @MathewHD ty for your comment. Yes you are right. It works. I apologize for not resolving this on my own and bothering the SO community. I am self-made programmer and I am working with C# the last couple of weeks. I will be more careful next time. Please up-vote to close the question because the answer was simpler than I thought. Thank you again for your reply and I will read how return works because I was not aware of its use.

Comment: No problem it's fine as long as the issue is solved :D.

Comment: And for closing the question I could write an answer and you could accept, but I myself can't close questions because I don't have even close to enough reputation for that.

Comment: @MathewHD Ok you can post a short answer. Also it could be really helpful to post an informative link on how return works in c#. I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want somehow is when the message box is triggered by one of the
> three if-statements to halt the execution for the rest of the
> function.

If you want to halt further execution of a function in c# you can use `return;` which exits out of the current function, without executing any further code.

```cs
private bool ExampleVoid() {
    MessageBox.Show("The file imported is an invalid layout file! \n Please check that 
        + you have imported the correct one.", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK, 
        MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
    
    // Return out of function because an error happened
    return;
}
```

Beware that if your function returns something for example a bool you need to add the corresponding values tot the return statment. In the case of a bool function eiter false or true.

**Example:**

```cs
private bool ExampleBool() {
    // Halt Execution of Function and return out of it
    return false;

   // Code Below the return statement is not executed
}
```

[Return Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return)